# Merging DataFrames no longer working after switching from Pandas 0.17.1 to Pandas 0.23.3

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge two DataFrames on a list of key values, with only one value in each DataFrame not being merged on. While this worked in an older version of Python/Pandas, it no longer functions and gives me an error.

I was previously working in Python 2.6.6 and Pandas 0.17.1, but have switched to Python 2.7.5 and Pandas 0.23.3. I merged like so:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(form_1, form_2, on = key_values, how = 'outer')
```

where form_1 and form_2 are DataFrames which both contain the headers ['ID1', 'ID2', 'visdate', 'visday', 'vismonth', 'visno', 'visyear', 'var'], and key_values containing ['ID1', 'ID2', 'visdate', 'visday', 'vismonth', 'visno', 'visyear'].

I expect merged_df to be a DataFrame containing containing the column headers ['ID1', 'ID2', 'visdate', 'visday', 'vismonth', 'visno', 'visyear', 'var_x', 'var_y']. I am instead given this error:

**ValueError: The column label 'ID1' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.**

If I get rid of ID1, I recieve the error for ID2, and if both are gone I get the error for visdate, etc.

Comment: What is the output of `[s for s in form_1.columns if 'ID1' in s]` ?

Comment: I think the problem is that one or both of your dataframes has multiple columns with the same label. double check that form_1.columns isn't something like `['ID1', 'ID2', 'visdate'.....'var', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'visdate'....]`

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns`. You must have a `MultiIndex`, in which case there's no way that list you're providing is truly the Index. If you have just a normal Index, the error should be different: `MergeError: Data columns not unique: Index(['ID1', 'ID1'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @ifly6 [('ID1',)]

Comment: What is the type of `form_1.columns`? I initially thought like kkawabat in that there are duplicate columns with the same names. But looking at that output, ALollz is probably right: there's a MultiIndex there.

Comment: That tuple indicates you have a MultiIndex, though the lack of any label in the second level means you probably don't need it. Figure out where this went wrong and fix it upstream. The hacky fix at this stage would be do to `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)`

Comment: @ALollz You're right, it is a `MultiIndex`. The output is 'MultiIndex(levels=[[u'ID1', u'ID2', u'var', u'visdate', u'visday', u'vismonth', u'visno', u'visyear']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]])'

Comment: What does it look like when you say `form_1`?